# how to work with background task for my application in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-task

Can any one please let me know how to work with background task for my application.

There are two scenarios in my application

1. If the user try to login when the wifi is enabled after clicking on login button if the wifi is disabled how to check in this scenario.
2. If the user login's and goes to another page and click on start button. So if the user opens the app it should be in the same page from where he/she went off.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method on login button click,

```
 public static bool CheckNetworkConnection()
    {
        var networkInterface = NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType;

        bool isConnected = false;
        if ((networkInterface == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)||(networkInterface== NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandGsm)||(networkInterface==NetworkInterfaceType.MobileBroadbandCdma))
            isConnected = true;

        else if (networkInterface == NetworkInterfaceType.None)
            isConnected = false;
        return isConnected;
    }
```

if internet connection is available, it will return true if not it ll return false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use background task by adding your app into lock screen apps.you have to trigger respective background task.It will get executed when needed.App must call RequestAccessAsync before registering any of the background trigger types.You cannot reference elements of your app user interface (UI) in a background task because the UI elements in your app are not running.Background tasks supported in WP8.1 only,not in WP8.

Please read msdn [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh977056(v=win.10).aspx).

check this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9)

you can write background task [step by step](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj710184.aspx)

Two question are nowhere related to background task,I will describe in short:
1)For network access you can use `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()`.
2)Please check Fast app resume support for windows phone 8.